# How to reduce font size on a defined css style?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile [demo page](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/#list-linked) has a nifty listview widget which I want to use.
However, I'd like to reduce the font size of the `<li>` elements (just the `<li>` elements in that particular list, not any other).

How do I pull that off?

Comment: I'm probably missing something. Why not just adding an overriding CSS settings?

Comment: I guess you'd pull that off with regular CSS, just target the right elements ?

Comment: @Itay Can you show me specifically how to alter those elements?

Comment: Give the list view an id or a class and override it `#listview > .ui-btn or .ui-li { font-size: .... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `<link>` to jquery-mobile.css in your head `<head>` element in your html file first, next line add a `<link>` to your site.css file. In your site.css add:

```
.ui-link-inherit{
    font-size:80%
}
```

ui-link-inherit is the class name jquery mobile gives each list item (`<li>`) in a list in the demo link you provided, your site.css file will override the styles defined in the jquery-mobile.css file because its link follows on the next line after the jquery css link (this is why its called cascading style sheets). Please note I am making up my own names for both the jquery css file and your website css file just for example sake.

You can also do this with an inline css style, instead of a external css file like my site.css example, so:

```
<style>
  .ui-link-inherit{
        font-size:80%
    }
</style>
```

Again just make sure your `<style>` element comes after the link to the jquery mobile css file.